# Gnuplot link all points on edges and fill the area

Tags: gnuplot

I have x-y data like this:

```
133.322 1073    
399.966 1073    
799.932 1073    
1333.22 1073    
133.322 1078    
399.966 1078    
799.932 1078    
1333.22 1078    
133.322 1083    
399.966 1083    
799.932 1083    
1333.22 1083    
133.322 1088    
399.966 1088
799.932 1088    
1333.22 1088    
133.322 1093    
399.966 1093    
799.932 1093    
1333.22 1093    
133.322 1098    
399.966 1098    
799.932 1098    
1333.22 1098    
133.322 1103
399.966 1103
799.932 1103
1333.22 1103
1333.22 1108
```

[image: data plotted with points]

What I what to get is like this:
[image: lines connect points on the edges]

or [image: fill the area]

How can I do it with Gnuplot?  I need to plot many other data in this way. So a common solution would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: are the datapoints always in a strict grid or could there also be a datapoint, e.g. 1000,1090 and 1500,1090 or could they be completely random?

Comment: @theozh It is completely random.

Comment: do you want a convex polygon or a concave polygon containing all points?

Comment: A convex polygon or a concave polygon is fine. I am open to any solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an attempt to draw an outline around random points.
Mathematicians probably might have ideas for a better procedure.

The procedure:

1. determine the bounding box for the datapoints, i.e. the extremal points for left,top,right,bottom which typically define a tetragon, but could also be a trigon or 2-gon
2. for each "quadrant", i.e. left/top, top/right, right/bottom, bottom/left, check whether the other points are outside of this polygon via determining the curvature (or orientation) between the two extreme points and a given point.
3. sort the outside points with ascending or descending x depending on the quadrant, basically sort the outline path "clockwise". Problem: gnuplot has no sort function. You could use an external program, but I generally prefer a *gnuplot-only* solution which makes it a bit longer.
4. remove all points which lead to a concave outline, this might need several iterations.

I would be happy to see simpler solutions. Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

**Code:**

```
### find and fill outline of random distributed points
reset session

# create some random test data
set samples 50
set table $Data
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))*100):(invnorm(rand(0))*100) w table
unset table
# if you have a file, skip the above test data section
# and uncomment the following 3 lines and put your filename
#set table $Data
#    plot "myData.dat" u 1:2 w table
#unset table

# get the coordinates of the leftmost, topmost, rightmost, and bottommost points
# in case of multiple points with leftmost x-value take the one with the topmost y-value
# similar of the other extreme points
#
# function to initialize extreme point cordinates
Init(x,y) = (Lx=column(x),Ly=column(y), \
             Tx=column(x),Ty=column(y), \
             Rx=column(x),Ry=column(y), \
             Bx=column(x),By=column(y) )
# find extreme point coordinates
GetExtremes(x,y) = (Lx>column(x) ? (Lx=column(x),Ly=column(y)) : \
                     (Lx==column(x) && Ly<column(y) ? Ly=column(y) : NaN), \
                   Ty<column(y) ? (Tx=column(x),Ty=column(y)) : \
                     (Ty==column(y) && Tx<column(x) ? Tx=column(x) : NaN), \
                   Rx<column(x) ? (Rx=column(x),Ry=column(y)) : \
                     (Rx==column(x) && Ry>column(y) ? Ry=column(y) : NaN), \
                   By>column(y) ? (Bx=column(x),By=column(y)) : \
                     (By==column(y) && Bx>column(x) ? Bx=column(x) : NaN))
set table $Dummy
    plot n=0 $Data u (n==0?(Init(1,2),n=n+1):GetExtremes(1,2)) w table
unset table
# put extremal points into array 1=left,2=top,3=right,4=bottom 
# and 5=left again for closed line of the extremal polygon
array EPx[5] = [Lx,Tx,Rx,Bx,Lx]
array EPy[5] = [Ly,Ty,Ry,By,Ly]

# (re-)define sgn() function such that sgn(NaN) gives NaN (gnuplot would give 0)
mysgn(x) = x==x ? sgn(x) : NaN

# function to determine orientation of the curves through 3 points A,B,C
# output: -1=clockwise; +1=counterclockwise (mathematical positive); NaN if one point is NaN
Orientation(xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc) = mysgn((xb-xa)*(yc-ya)-(xc-xa)*(yb-ya))

# determine outside points for all 4 "quadrants"
# a point is outside
set datafile missing NaN   # important for removing points from outline
array SinglePoint[1]       # dummy array for plotting a single point
array EmptyLines[2]        # dummy array for plotting two emtpy lines
array OutsidePoints[4]     # number of outside points for each "quadrant"
set table $OutsidePoints
    do for [n=1:4] {
        i=0
        plot SinglePoint u (EPx[n]):(EPy[n]) w table
        plot $Data u 1:(Orientation(EPx[n],EPy[n],$1,$2,EPx[n%4+1],EPy[n%4+1]) < 0 ? (i=i+1,$2):NaN) w table 
        plot SinglePoint u (EPx[n%4+1]):(EPy[n%4+1]) w table
        plot EmptyLines u ("") w table
        OutsidePoints[n] = i+2
    }
unset table

# sort the outside points of the 4 "quadrants" by in- or decreasing x 
# since gnuplot has no built-in sort function it's a bit lengthy
AllOutsidePoints = (sum [i=1:4] OutsidePoints[i])-3    # reduce by 3 double extremal points
array Xall[AllOutsidePoints]
array Yall[AllOutsidePoints]
idx = 0
do for [n=1:4] {
    array  X[OutsidePoints[n]]   # initialize array
    array  Y[OutsidePoints[n]]   # initialize array
    set table $Dummy
        plot $OutsidePoints u (X[$0+1]=$1, Y[$0+1]=$2) index n-1 w table
    unset table
    # Bubblesort, inefficient but simple
    SortDirection = n<3 ? +1 : -1     # n=1,2: +1=ascending, n=3,4: -1=descending
    do for [j=OutsidePoints[n]:2:-1] {
        do for [i=1:j-1] {
            if ( X[i]*SortDirection > X[i+1]*SortDirection) {
                tmp=X[i]; X[i]=X[i+1]; X[i+1]=tmp;
                tmp=Y[i]; Y[i]=Y[i+1]; Y[i+1]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    # append array to datablock
    set print $Outline append
        do for [i=1:|X|-(n==4?0:1)] { print sprintf("%g %g",X[i],Y[i]) }
    set print
    # create an array for all sorted outside datapoints
    last = |X|-(n==4?0:1)
    do for [i=1:last] { 
        Xall[idx+i]=X[i]
        Yall[idx+i]=Y[i]
    }
    idx=idx+last
}

# function checks convexity: result: >0: concave, 1=convex
# Orientation: -1=clockwise, 0=straight, +1=counterclockwise, NaN=undefined point
# function actually doesn't depend on n, just to shorten the function call later
CheckConvexity(n) = (Convex=1,sum [i=2:|Xall|-1] ( idx0=i-1, idx1=i, idx2=i+1, Convex=Convex && \
       (Orientation(Xall[idx0],Yall[idx0],Xall[idx1],Yall[idx1],Xall[idx2],Yall[idx2])<0)),Convex)

# put array to datablock
set table $Convex
    plot Xall u (Xall[$0+1]):(Yall[$0+1]) w table
unset table

# remove concave points (could take several iterations)
Count=0
while (!CheckConvexity(0)) {
    Count = Count+1
    print sprintf("Iteration %d ...",Count)
    # set concave points to NaN
    do for [i=2:|Xall|-1] {
        idx0=i-1; idx1=i; idx2=i+1
        if (Orientation(Xall[idx0],Yall[idx0],Xall[idx1],Yall[idx1],Xall[idx2],Yall[idx2])>=0) {
            Yall[idx1] = NaN
        }
    }
    # remove NaN points by plotting it to datablock
    set table $Convex
        plot Xall u (Xall[$0+1]):(Yall[$0+1]) w table
    unset table
    # create new X,Y array with reduced size
    array Xall[|$Convex|]
    array Yall[|$Convex|]
    # put datablock into array again for next iteration if necessary
    set table $Dummy
        plot $Convex u (Xall[$0+1]=$1):(Yall[$0+1]=$2) w table
    unset table
}
print sprintf("Convex after %d iterations.",Count)

set object 1 rect from Lx,By to Rx,Ty dt 3
set offsets graph 0.01, graph 0.01, graph 0.01, graph 0.01
set key out top center horizontal

plot \
    keyentry w l ls 0 ti "Bounding box", \
    $Outline u 1:2 w filledcurves closed lc rgb "green" fs solid 0.1 not noautoscale, \
    EPx u (EPx[$0+1]):(EPy[$0+1]) w l lc rgb "black" ti "Extremal polygon", \
    $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc rgb "blue" ti "Points inside polygon", \
    $OutsidePoints u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" ti "Points outside polygon", \
    Xall u (Xall[$0+1]):(Yall[$0+1]) w l lw 1 lc rgb "green" ti "Concave outline", \
    $Convex u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lw 2 lc rgb "orange" ti "Convex outline", \
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (second procedure)

I agree with @Christoph that gnuplot is probably not the optimal tool for doing this but nevertheless you can do it :-). Here is a shorter procedure.

The procedure:

1. search for the bottommost point and if there are several points with bottommost y-value take the one with the rightmost x-coordinate.
2. from this point calculate the angles `a` to all other points. Find the point with the smallest difference to a target angle, which at the beginning is `aTar=0`. If there are several points with the same smallest difference angle take the point with the largest distance `dMax`. Add this point to the outline.
3. set the new target angle to the angle of the line between the previous and the new found point.
4. go again to 2 until you will end up with the first point `BxStart,ByStart`.

I hope my description is somehow understandable. Although the code is shorter than the first version it might be less efficient because it hast to go multiple times (i.e. number of outline points) through all points. Worst case would be points which are already aligned on a circle.

**Code:**

```
### fill outline of random points
reset session

# create some test data
set samples 50
set table $Data
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))*100):(invnorm(rand(0))*100) w table
unset table
### if you have a file, uncomment the following lines and put your filename
#set table $Data
#     plot "myData.dat" u 1:2 w table
#unset table

# Angle by dx,dy (range: -90°<= angle < 270°), NaN if dx==dy==0
set angle degrees
Angle(dx,dy) = dx==dx && dy==dy ? dx==0 ? dy==0 ? NaN : sgn(dy)*90 : dx<0 ? 180+atan(dy/dx) : atan(dy/dx) : NaN
# Angle by dx,dy (range: 0°<= angle < 360°), NaN if dx==dy==0
Angle360(dx,dy) = (a_tmp=Angle(dx,dy), a_tmp==a_tmp) ? a_tmp-360*floor(a_tmp/360.) : NaN


# get the coordinates of the bottommost point
# in case of multiple points with bottommost y-coordinate take the one with the rightmost x-coordinate
Init(x,y) = (Bx=column(x),By=column(y))

GetExtremes(x,y) = (By>column(y) ? (Bx=column(x),By=column(y)) : \
                   (By==column(y) && Bx>column(x) ? Bx=column(x) : NaN))
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u ($0==0?Init(1,2):GetExtremes(1,2)) w table
unset table
print sprintf("Bottommost point: %g,%g:", Bx,By)

# Distance
Dist(x0,y0,x1,y1) = sqrt((x1-x0)**2 + (y1-y0)**2)

# function for getting the next outline point
GetNext(x,y) = (a=Angle360(column(x)-Bx,column(y)-By), aDiff=(a<aTar?a+360-aTar:a-aTar),\
                d=Dist(Bx,column(x),By,column(y)), \
                aMin>aDiff ? (aNext=a, aMin=aDiff,dMax=d,xNext=column(x),yNext=column(y)) : \
                aMin==aDiff ? dMax<d ? (dMax=d, xNext=column(x),yNext=column(y)) : NaN : NaN)

BxStart=Bx;  ByStart=By
set print $Outline append
    print sprintf("% 9g % 9g",BxStart,ByStart)  # add starting point to outline
    aTar=0
    while 1 {  # endless loop
        aMin=360;  dMax=0
        set table $Dummy
            plot  $Data u (GetNext(1,2)) w table
        unset table
        print sprintf("% 9g % 9g",xNext,yNext)
        Bx=xNext;  By=yNext; aTar=aNext
        if (xNext==BxStart && yNext==ByStart) { break } # exit loop
    }
set print

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ti "Datapoints",\
     $Outline u 1:2 w l lc rgb "red" ti "Convex Outline"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Impressive, though I prefer using the right tool for the right job ;)

Comment: @Christoph, I agree it is lengthy and gnuplot probably not the optimal tool for this. In your opinion, what would be the tools for this type of task? Mathematica, Matlab, Octave...? I assume also my shorter second approach will still not convince you to do it with gnuplot... ;-).

Comment: I love gnuplot, and you'll find a bunch of answers from me of pre array/table gnuplot versions for some nice hackery.  But for advanced data processing I always use some script to process the data, in my case in Python with numpy/scipy. On-the-fly or preprocessing depends on the actual amount of data.

Comment: Very nice. Agree with @Christoph, but I add that it is very handy to have this already in gnuplot for small problems. For instances, I find very convenient to do quick derivatives, integrals or histograms on gnuplot.